# What authentication techniques can be used by QKD Systems?

Tags: authentication, key-exchange, quantum-key-distribution

As it is well known that QKD systems are prone to simple MITM attacks… what authentication techniques are being used in QKD to prevent those attacks in practice?

Comment: If you have a shared secret, you can use universal hashing.

Comment: yeah I was just reading about this  , are there practical implementations of universal hashing ?

Comment: [GMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode) and [Poly1305](http://cr.yp.to/mac.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard answer in the research literature is to use information-theoretically secure message authentication codes, typically universal hashing (aka Carter-Wegman authenticators).  Of course, you could use computationally-secure message authentication codes, like CMAC or HMAC, if you wanted, though that would partly defeat one of the reasons for using QKD.

That said, in practice QKD is a bit silly.  QKD solves a problem that most people don't have, so it is basically a fancy useless toy (albeit a very expensive one).  If you're considering using QKD in some practical deployment, my advice is: skip the QKD, and just use a TLS or IPSec VPN.  There, I saved you $50,000; don't spend it all in one place!

Comment: D.W , Yes agree very much with you,  am kinda working on a write up , "QKD Is cryptographic baloney" , so was getting as much info as possible to support.

Comment: @sashank: perhaps read this related [answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2721/555) of mine.